# ExecutorService doesn't call run() in Runnable

Tags: android, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, asmack

I've come across a strange issue in the asmack library for Android. The library uses an ExecutorService to parse incoming packets like that:

```
private ExecutorService listenerExecutor;

listenerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {

        public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable,
                    "Smack Listener Processor (" + connection.connectionCounterValue + ")");
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    });

(...)

listenerExecutor.submit(new ListenerNotification(packet));

(...)

/**
 * A runnable to notify all listeners of a packet.
 */
private class ListenerNotification implements Runnable {

    private Packet packet;

    public ListenerNotification(Packet packet) {
        this.packet = packet;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (ListenerWrapper listenerWrapper : connection.recvListeners.values()) {
            listenerWrapper.notifyListener(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

It all works fine until a point when the submit() method is called, the constructor for ListenerNotification is also called but the run() method in ListenerNotification is no longer called.

What could be the reason for this? Are there some mechanisms in ExecutorService that may cause a call to submit to be ignored?

Comment: Does `ListenerNotification.run()` run even once? Have you tried using the default ThreadFactory rather than your own?

Comment: Yes, it runs for a while and then stops. This is not deterministic nor reproducible which makes me wonder... I have not made changes to this library code - I'm only using it in two of my projects. I used the same library previously and I had no problems of this nature and now they appeared.

I even removed my own listener from the listener list that is being iterated over in the run() method because I thought maybe whatever I'm doing is taking too long but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try an older version of the lib and see if it does happen there too now. Maybe the single thread executor is in a somehow 'locked' state. This is the first report of such a behavior of aSmack I've heard of.

Comment: Yes, the thread was, in fact, blocked by my own code.

Answer (score 0):

As was to be expected the fault was on my side.

I implemented a Roster Packet listener in my code and overrode the processPacket method:

```
@Override
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
    if (packet instanceof RosterPacket) {
        RosterPacket rosterPacket = (RosterPacket) packet;
        Logger.d(LOGTAG, "Initial roster packet received: " + rosterPacket.getRosterItemCount());
        mConnection.removePacketListener(this);
        fireOnInitialRosterPacketReceived(rosterPacket);
    }
}
```

However, my internal listener calling method introduced an infinite loop:

```
private void fireOnInitialRosterPacketReceived(RosterPacket rosterPacket) {
    Iterator<SessionListener> it = mSessionListeners.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        // it.next().onInitialRosterPacketReceived(mConnection,
        // rosterPacket);
    }
}
```

This blocked the thread started by the executor so that the subsequent calls to submit didn't fire the thread again.